# color one cell that has a multicolumn in it

Tags: color

Hi I want to colour the cell with "SMI" in it.

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{tabularx} % LINE-A
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{lrr}
               \toprule
    Name  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{1989}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{1990}} \\
    \midrule
     \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}{ABB Ltd } & \multicolumn{1}{l}{SMI} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{SMI} \\
   Actelion & \multicolumn{1}{l}{SMI} &  \\
    \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I have now coloured the cell "ABB Ltd" but how can I colour the cell "SMI"?

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor{gray}SMI}`. But why all those `\multicolumn`s? Most of them seem useless.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two solutions. Note with `booktabs` there is a white strip at the top and the bottom of coloured cells. If you don't want it, you can replace booktabs with `boldline + cellspace` to achieve a similar effect:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{tabularx} % LINE-A
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{cellspace, boldline}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lrr}
    \toprule
    Name & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{1989}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{1990}} \\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.8}{ABB Ltd } & \multicolumn{1}{l}{SMI} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{SMI} \\
    Actelion & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.8}SMI} & \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}



\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{Slrr}
    \hlineB{2}
    Name & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{1989}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{1990}} \\
    \hlineB{1.5}
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.8}{ABB Ltd } & \multicolumn{1}{l}{SMI} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{SMI} \\
    Actelion & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.8}SMI} & \\
    \hlineB{2}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]